# What would a dependent multicategory be?

Tags: category-theory

A multicategory maps a list of inputs to a single output.

What would a dependent multicategory mapping inputs that depend on each other be?

You can do the usual sort of slice construction over polycategories but I can't figure out how to factor the constructor into mapping over dependent lists of arguments and I'm not sure this is the right approach to take.

Comment: I believe this is an open problem.

Comment: @varkor I assume the problem is with a fully general definition right/working out the details? I learned the product in a slice category is a pullback so a dependent multicategory would take as input a pullback of a bunch of arrows right? But I assume the problem is that people want to make a very generic definition and not just handle the easiest case. Also how to use that def ergonomically seems confusing

Comment: The problem is that a multicategory has a family of multimorphisms, ranging over the possible domains. However, in a category with finite limits, the domains depend on the morphisms. So there's a difficult circularity to capture when you move to multicategories; you can't specify the domains of the multimorphisms without knowing what the multimorphisms are, but you can't specify what they are without knowing what their domains are.